# Converting ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::ASSETS_DIR for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a plugin that I would like to use that has the following line in it:

```
PATH_TO_ASSETS = ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::ASSETS_DIR + File::SEPARATOR
```

This is erring now with:

```
const_missing': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::ASSETS_DIR (NameError)
```

Any idea how I can get this to work with Rails 3? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ASSETS_DIR` was taken out in Rails 3. It would have been defined as `Rails.public_path` or `'public'` if `Rails.public_path` was undefined.

`ActionController::Base.helpers.config.assets_dir` seems to be what it was replaced with